# Remote ACCESS - SSH listening port filtered out by Firewall?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, firewall

I am trying to access a remote server, with no physical access.

I have accidentally changed the previous listening port in SSH and forgot to change it in the firewall rules. In firewall 15000 is enabled, but SSH configuration listens on another port 20000.

Every solutions in the net seems to need physical access.

Is there a way to channel my SSH connections at port 15000 to 20000 ?

Answer (score 1):

If SSH was the only way you were able to access this server before you changed the firewall settings, you have unfortunately locked yourself out of that machine.  You will need physical access to fix it or be able to speak with your hardware provider to have someone there help you out.

You can forward ports to "channel" your SSH connections, but this would require you to already have SSH access or some other means of administration.